# How to drag a formula to the right in Google Spreadsheets using a script with an array?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Is there any fast way of dragging a formula to the 10 columns on the right using a script?

I'm using:

```
function copiaFormula(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

  for (i=0;i<10;i++){
    var cell=sheet.getRange(5, i+1);
    cell.setFormulaR1C1("=SUM(R[-3]C[0]:R[-1]C[0])");
   }
}
```

This writes the formulas correctly, but it would be faster if they were pushed to an array an then written.

Thanks in advance for helping!﻿

Answer (score 1):

Instead you can get a range of cells and apply the formula as below:

```
function copiaFormula(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
    var cell=sheet.getRange(5, 1,1,10);
    cell.setFormulaR1C1("=SUM(R[-3]C[0]:R[-1]C[0])");
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: It doesn't answer my question, but it is an interesting solution for sure! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it answers your question. Have you tried to use ARRAYFORMULA to enables the display of values returned from an array formula into multiple rows and/or columns and the use of non-array functions with arrays. You can find more information on the link:

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

This will do it the way you're suggesting: by pushing the formulas to an array and then writing the array to the sheet. But I don't see a reason to do it this way, and I think @KRR posted the more elegant solution (I originally wrote similar code until I saw he or she beat me to it).

```
function copiaFormula(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

  var numCols = 10;
  var formulas = [];

  for(var i=0 ; i<numCols ; i++){
    formulas[i] = "=SUM(R[-3]C[0]:R[-1]C[0])";
  }

  sheet.getRange(5, 1, 1, formulas.length).setFormulasR1C1([formulas]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that!